# What are the exponential alternatives that are skipped in dynamic programming for longest increasing subsequence?

Tags: np-complete, dynamic-programming, subsequences

I am trying to wrap my head around how dynamic programming helps avoid all possibilities that are exponential after reading **Chapter 8 NP-complete problems** of *Algorithms by Dasgupta et al.* where it says:

> So far in this book we have seen the most brilliant successes of this quest, algorithmic techniques that defeat the specter of exponentiality: greedy algorithms, **dynamic programming**, linear programming (while divide-and-conquer typically yields faster algorithms for problems we can already solve in polynomial time).

Going back to **Chapter 6 Dynamic programming**, I followed along the *longest increasing subsequence problem* that [this video also shows how to solve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE2b_-XfVDk&ab_channel=TusharRoy-CodingMadeSimple). It seemed to me that we were considering all other choices in the solution for the sequence $3, 4, -1, 0, 6, 2, 3$, but only did this with $n^2$ time.

What are the other possible subsequences that would reveal that this problem is exponential in nature without dynamic programming? I can see that in the `0-1 Knapsack problem` there are $2^n$ possibilities to consider but can't see the exponential counterpart of the `longest increasing subsequence problem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go over all $2^n$ subsequences. For each one, check whether it is increasing.

There are two meanings of subsequence: *contiguous* subsequence and *arbitrary* subsequence. For example, $1,3$ is a non-contiguous subsequence of $1,2,3$.

Formally, a subsequence of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is a sequence $a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_m}$ for some $1 \leq m \leq n$, where $1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_m \leq n$. A subsequence is contiguous if it is of the form $a_i,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_j$, that is, if it contains all elements from $a_i$ to $a_j$.

A sequence of length $n$ has $2^n-1$ subsequences, only $\binom{n+1}{2}$ of which are contiguous.

For example, here are all subsequences of $a,b,c$:
$$
a \\ b \\ c \\ a,b \\ a,c \\ b,c \\ a,b,c
$$
Of these, only $a,c$ is not contiguous.

Comment: Oh. So this means have an array of `0` or `1` on whether or not a number is included in a subsequence?

Comment: What is a general subsequence? I haven't been able to find it on google but I have for contiguous.

Comment: Use your imagination.

Comment: I see you changed from `general` to `arbitrary` subsequence. Thanks. Wouldn't have known what my imagination came up with was correct.

Comment: @heretoinfinity, on most (if not all) modern (meaning in the recent 20 or much more years) situations, a subsequence means what is meant by subsequence or arbitrary subsequence by Yuval here. A contiguous subsequence is also commonly called as a sublist, a subarray, or a substring.

Comment: @John, Thank you very much for the context. I am new at this.